# What kind of conditions can I use in a for loop using PHP?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am new in PHP. I know a little bit about how for loops work. Using this format: `(initial; conditions; increment)` why doesn't this loop work? What kind of conditions are allowed?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  $name = "Biswajit";
  for ($i = 1; $name[$i] == "w"; $i++) {

    echo "hello";

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition can be any expression whatsoever that can be usefully evaluated to `true` or `false`.

The condition is tested once at the start of each iteration of the loop. The loop **ends** as soon as one of these tests gives false.

Your example condition `$name[$i] == "w"` is syntactically valid, but will end the loop immediately, because `$name[1]` is `i`, not `w`. (Note that string characters start from 0.) Maybe you meant to write `$name[$i] != "w"`.

Answer (score 0):

So a `for` loop in PHP is pretty much like any other `for` loop in any other language.

Basically, you'll be able to put in condition that results to a boolean (notably `==`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`).

Here's a basic example of a `for` loop in PHP printing a number:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  echo $i;
}
```

Hope this simple example can help! :)